# How to deploy code to hundreds of servers efficiently

Tags: windows, performance, powershell, robocopy, copy-item

We have hundreds of VMs running application, and deploying code to all of them at a time is getting challenging. Deploying them sequentially using robocopy is taking hours and running them as parallel threads/jobs is taking up deployment server CPU and system is hosing up.

What are the effective ways of handling this situation ?

Comment: Probably more on-topic on Server Fault; not sure. It appears to me that an efficient deployment tool, instead of processing one *target host* after the other, would process one *source file* after the other (so that each file has to be read only once at the source host) and might possibly make use of some network broadcasting mechanism (so that each file has to be transmitted only once, or at least fewer times than if it were sent once to each target host). I don't know whether there are utilities that do this.

Comment: Using software like PDQ Deploy ( Pro i think. Other software deployment solutions could work to.) you could set up a source directory that all targeted systems could pull data from and execute if need be.

Comment: I'd look into using a folder sync program to replicate the source folder onto the destination servers.